# Invert colors OpenCV Java Api

Tags: java, c++, api, opencv, computer-vision

How do I invert the colors of an image stored in `Mat image` in the Java API of OpenCV? Using `image.inv()` gets me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inv()` method will try to take inverse of the matrix that's why it is failing (most probably your image matrix is not invertible).

You can subtract two images from each other, so you can create an image with all values are 255 and then extract original one from it, if that is what you mean by invert the colors.

Answer (score 14):

`inv()` is used to calculate [inverse matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html); use [bitwise_not](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not) instead:

```
Core.bitwise_not( image, image );
```

Answer (score 10):

Just in case:

```
Mat invertcolormatrix= new Mat(image.rows(),image.cols(), image.type(), new Scalar(255,255,255));

Core.subtract(invertcolormatrix, image, image);
```