# Grayscaling inverted image in OpenCV Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I want to convert an inverted image to grayscale in openCV, i used with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547212/invert-colors-opencv-java-api) to inverting BGR image, but i get an Error regarding the Imgproc.cvtColor method.

This is the logcat :

```
01-06 13:43:01.085: E/cv::error()(8837): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/org.opencv.imgproc(8837): imgproc::cvtColor_11() caught cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): Process: com.example.irisrecog, PID: 8837
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.irisrecog/com.example.irisrecog.MainActivity}: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): ]
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2850)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837): ]
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_1(Native Method)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:4598)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at com.example.irisrecog.MainActivity.segmentasi(MainActivity.java:240)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at com.example.irisrecog.MainActivity.deteksiIrisMata(MainActivity.java:283)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at com.example.irisrecog.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:135)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2840)
01-06 13:43:01.095: E/AndroidRuntime(8837):     ... 10 more
```

and below is my code for grayscaling an inverted image :

```
//invert matrix - bgrFrame
Mat invertedMat = new Mat(bgrFrame.rows(), bgrFrame.cols(), bgrFrame.type());
Mat invertColorMat = new Mat(bgrFrame.rows(), bgrFrame.cols(), bgrFrame.type(), new Scalar(255,255,255));
Core.subtract(invertColorMat, bgrFrame, invertedMat);
//grayscaling inverted matrix
Mat grayscaledMat = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(invertedMat, grayscaledMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // this line caused an error
```

Is there any error in my code?
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried converting to grayscale first and then inverting? No reason to substract three channels and then convert as far as i can tell.

Comment: is it possible that your `bgrFrame` is `BGRA` instead? afaik that is the standard type on android. Pleae try `Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY` instead and maybe adjust your `Scalar(255,255,255)`

Comment: @Mailerdaimon my goal is detecting pupil boundary like in [this tutorial](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/pupil-detection-from-an-eye-image/), that tutorial says that I has to inverting image first than grayscaling first. Is it possible if I grayscaling it first then inverting, the result is same as in that tutorial? I'm sorry if I'm wrong, I just started my first project on OpenCV, and I just following that tutorial. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Micka I have tried Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY, but still no luck. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you print `invertedMat.type()` and `invertedMat.channels()` please? The exception tells you that there is something wrong with the number of channels of your source Mat, as far as I see...

Comment: @SahidNurA it should make no difference as you dont use the inverted RGB image.. so i would suggest the following: convert to grayscale, invert and then threshold. berak did exactly this in his answer and as far as is can tell it should work. As for the Error: please follow the advice from Micka and check the type and channels to see if everything is fine with your image.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to invert the image manually, there's a flag for the thresholding, that does that automatically:

```
Mat grayscaledMat = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(bgrFrame, grayscaledMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Mat thresh = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(grayscaledMat, thresh, 30, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

[image]

---

but your error-msg complains, that the input to cvtColor had neither 3 nor 4 channels, so it was either a grayscale, or an total empty/invalid img.