# OpenCV4Android 3 / JavaCV: convert and invert image fails

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.0, javacv

I convert a CvCameraViewFrame into the Mat type using inputFrame.rgba(). Now, I want to invert it using Mat.inv(). Here's the code fragment:

```
Mat invertedMRgba = mRgba.clone();
invertedMRgba.convertTo(invertedMRgba, CvType.CV_32F);
invertedMRgba = invertedMRgba.inv();
```

The code compiles. However it fails on the last line, with an Assertion failed:

```
09-18 16:40:12.150: E/cv::error()(17825): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed 
(type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F) in double cv::invert(cv::InputArray, 
cv::OutputArray, int), file /builds/master_pack-
android/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp, line 798
```

Well, the error messages tells me to convert either in CV_32F or in CV_64F, which is exactly what I did... (I also tried CV_64F without success.)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute the inverse matrix of an image? Probably you want to _negate_ the image

Comment: the `inv()` does not work, because it expects a single channel matrix, while your is 4 channels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invert colors OpenCV Java Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547212/invert-colors-opencv-java-api)